# where can i download geforce gt425m driver?

Tags: nvidia, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Hi people i have just installed ubuntu 11.10, so i do not know much about it.

My problem is that ubuntu does not recognize my graphic card.

I use intel HD integrated (i3 processor)
Nvidia geforce GT 425m.

But ubuntu does not recognice my graphic card, under system info it says 
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 370 @ 2.40GHz × 4
Graphic:Unknown
OS-type:bit

Hope some one can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run jockey (just type `jockey` in terminal) to see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a sandybridge processor, which has an integrated graphics card.

It uses Optimus and there are no official drivers for Linux, which means you can only use the integrated graphics card (the one on your processor). However, there are tricks (like Ironhide) to use your nVidia card. See this [this link](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/610) for information on how to install it.

After it has been installed, open a terminal and enter

```
optirun glxspheres
```

If the Mpixels/sec is higher than 100, then it's working.

You can also use this

```
optirun glxinfo | grep render
```

Which will output your nVidia card information.

Comment: Ironhide is outdated now, you'd better use [Bumblebee 3.0 "Tumbleweed"](http://askubuntu.com/a/36936/6969)

Comment: @Lekensteyn I've installed Bumbleebee now, however it gives me significant lower results. I get 98 Mpixels/sec with "optirun glxspheres" whilst I get 150 Mpixels/sec with Ironhide.

Comment: for this release, use `VGL_READBACK=pbo optirun -c yuv glxspheres` (`VGL_READBACK=pbo` is the key here, `-c yuv` selects a different transport method). With the `VGL_READBACK=pbo` option set, some machines perform worse (notably using the `nouveau` driver)